# The use of app.py.disabled on openshift

Tags: python-2.7, openshift, paas

I recently created a python app on openshift. I found a file called app.py.disabled when I git cloned the repo. Can anyone explain what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-to-make-python-front-end

> Our Python 2.6 and 2.7 cartridges are wsgi-based:
>   http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial You will want to define
>   handlers for each. For example, the default application
>   (repo/wsgi/application) handles /health and /env specifically and
>   generically for everything else: ...
>
> You can override that with repo/app.py and use something like cherrypy
>   if you wanted to (see app.py.disabled as an example). Otherwise, it's
>   hardcoded to serve repo/wsgi/application by default.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new gear with each cartridge type [python-2.6, python-2.7, python-3.3] and when the code was cloned to my workstation, none of them contained an app.py.disabled file.  Can you give more information about how you created the application?  Did you use a specific quickstart or url?

Comment: I used the web console to make the project.